# StyleCI PHP cannot disable certain fixers

Tags: php, styleci

I'm using StyleCI to fix my code on the following repo: https://github.com/neneone/SnapeBot.
When I try to disable the `braces` filter, it says:

```
We failed to save your config. The provided fixer 'braces' cannot be disabled unless it was already enabled by your preset.
```

I tried to put `none` as `preset`, but it didn't work too.

Here is my StyleCI config:

```
preset: none

risky: false

enabled:
  ...

disabled:
  - braces
  - concat_without_spaces
  - hash_to_slash_comment
  - declare_equal_normalize
  - long_array_syntax
  - long_list_syntax
  - new_with_braces
  - yoda_style

finder:
  ...
```

I just want to disable that fixers cause I don't like them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `preset: none`, so nothing is enabled by default. You can not disable the fixer that not enabled by your preset. In another word, these fixers are already disabled.